# Можно ли вывести массив с помощью R::count RedbeanPHP?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Интересует задача

```
$perlink[] = R::count('articles', 'cat = ?', [$menu]);
```

$menu содержит значения 1,2,3, но выводится только одно Array ([0] => 12)
Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы выводился массив значений? Например Array ([0] => 12, [1] => 21, [2] => 27). На официальном сайте я так и не смог найти ничего про это, да и интернет перерыл весь.